# Error with this code?

Tags: c

So, I don't see what is flawed with my logic on this problem.

It reads the expression from left to right, and operands are floating point numbers.

However, my program gets stuck in the loop. It reads and assigns the final number, for example it assigns 10.5 to num1, but it never exits the loop.

```
int main(void)
{
    float num1, num2;
    char oper = 0;

    printf("Enter an expression: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);

    while (oper != ('\n' || EOF))
    {
        oper = getchar();
        scanf("%f", &num2);

        switch (oper)
        {
            case '+':
            num1 += num2;
            break;

            case '-':
            num1 -= num2;
            break;

            case '*':
            num1 *= num2;
            break;

            case '/':
            num1 /= num2;
            break;
        }

    }

    printf("Value of Expression: %.2f", num1);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Enter an expression: 1+2.5*3

Value of expression: 10.5
```

Comment: Note that your loop condition `while (oper != ('\n' || EOF))` is equivalent to `while (oper != 1)` since `'\n' || EOF` is always true (1).  You probably meant: `while (oper != '\n' && oper != EOF)`.  This is why your code gets stuck in a loop stuck in a loop stuck in a loop stuck in a loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just edited the code and tried that, same problem. It never exits the loop

Answer (score 5):

- `while (oper != ('\n' || EOF))` Here, `('\n' || EOF) == 1`, so the loop will not terminate unless you input the ASCII character that corresponds to 1 (which is unprintable). As Leffler points out, this should be `while (oper != '\n' && oper != EOF)` (though see the next point).
- You check `oper` in your while loop before you read from it, so your while loop will terminate one step "after" the newline/EOF. The while loop should actually be:

  ```
  while(1) {
      oper = getchar();
      if(oper == '\n' || oper == EOF) {
          break; // Exit out of loop, ignoring the rest of the code inside the loop.
      }

      scanf("%f", &num2);
      // ...
  }
  ```
- `getchar` returns an `int`, but `oper` is a `char`. Change `oper` to an `int` (`EOF` cannot be represented as a `char`)

Comment: @krazibiosvn Before, the `while` loop condition should evaluate true if the loop should continue. But this `if` statement needs to be taken if the loop _shouldn't_ continue, so I've inverted the condition. `oper == '\n' || oper == EOF` is the same as `!(oper != '\n' && oper != EOF)`

Answer (score 1):

Make oper an int. 255 is not equal to EOF

Answer (score 1):

You need to revise the loop ending conditions.  Your program is actually busy waiting for you to type another number after the first newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float num1, num2;

    printf("Enter an expression: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &num1) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("Num1: %f\n", num1);

    while (1)
    {
        int oper;
        if ((oper = getchar()) == EOF || oper == '\n')
            break;
        printf("Operator: %c\n", oper);
        if (scanf("%f", &num2) != 1)
            break;

        printf("Num2: %f\n", num2);
        switch (oper)
        {
        case '+':
            num1 += num2;
            break;

        case '-':
            num1 -= num2;
            break;

        case '*':
            num1 *= num2;
            break;

        case '/':
            num1 /= num2;
            break;
        }
        printf("num1 = %f\n", num1);
    }

    printf("Value of Expression: %.2f\n", num1);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code checks each input operation to make sure it was successful.  It also uses `int oper` instead of `char oper` to ensure that EOF is detected accurately.  And the key trick is not to ask for more input after the `getchar()` reads the newline; your program was stuck waiting for you to type something in response to the second `scanf()` call.  Notice how this code prints its inputs so you can tell what's going on.  When a program is misbehaving, it is one of the simpler techniques to find out what's going wrong.  When I saw `Operator:` and a blank line — and the program hanging — I knew very quickly what the trouble was.

Example run (program name: `stuck`):

```
$ ./stuck
Enter an expression: 1+2.5*3
Num1: 1.000000
Operator: +
Num2: 2.500000
num1 = 3.500000
Operator: *
Num2: 3.000000
num1 = 10.500000
Value of Expression: 10.50
$
```